# Wordpress error "Deprecated: The $control_id argument is deprecated since version 3.5.0!"

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I am getting these errors on my website https://hygienx.cleaning its coming on frontend you can see. these are the following errors i am getting:

Deprecated: The $control_id argument is deprecated since version 3.5.0! in /home/admin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/dev-tools/deprecation.php on line 304

Deprecated: Hook elementor/widgets/widgets_registered is deprecated since version 3.5.0! Use elementor/widgets/register instead. in /home/admin/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5758

Deprecated: Function Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register_widget_type is deprecated since version 3.5.0! Use register instead. in /home/admin/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5383

I am trying to solve this errors and make my website running properly.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a very old version of Elementor. Update the plugin and if you still see these warnings reach out to their support team and report the issue to them (seems like [you already did](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/deprecated-the-control_id-argument-is-deprecated-since-version-3-5-0-in/) though so wait for them to assist you with this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your complaint should be directed to Elementor. It's their code generating these WordPress core feature deprecation messages. Make sure you're up to date on plugins and WordPress core.

If your site has, in its `wp-config.php` file, a `true` value for `WP_DEBUG`, try removing it. If you have access to wp-cli this shell command does the trick.

```
wp config delete WP_DEBUG
```

Or, use a text editor to edit `wp-config.php` and remove the line mentioning `WP_DEBUG`. Explaining how to do that is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Turning off debug mode that way conceals the deprecation notices from your audience.